# ui-router (0.3.2) doesn't fire `$stateChangeStart` for regex state param on history back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-sfr1um?embed=1&file=app.js). Note that I am using `Angularjs@1.5.7` and `ui-router@0.3.2`.

It defines the following ui-router states:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('counter1', {
    url: '/counter1/{id:(NEW-ID-\d+|)}?detail',
    templateUrl: 'view/counter.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$interval', counterController]
  })
  .state('counter2', {
    url: '/counter2/:id?detail',
    templateUrl: 'view/counter.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$interval', counterController]
  })
```

Both states are identical, except `counter1` defines parameter `id` as regular expression while `counter2` defines it the simple way.

**The problem is that with this setup the `counterController`'s**

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => console.log('$stateChangeStart'))
```

**will only fire for the `counter2` route, not for `counter1` when the user uses the browser's *back* or *forward* function. The odd thing is that it DOES fire on e.g. `state.go()` or clicking on an `ui-sref` link.**

If the regex in the `counter1` route is changed to `{id:.*}` it does work as expected but for my use-case I need to define it as `{id:NEW-ID-\d+|}`. Is this a known bug and is there any other work-around to make sure `$stateChangeStart` is actually triggered correctly? I haven't found anything and would be grateful for ideas.

Comment: I actually have another case where I use `{id:(?:foo|bar)}` and there it works as expected... which makes me think maybe it's an issue with the regex actually but I've got no idea how.